# proper action on homogeneous space

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, homogeneous-spaces

Let $M = G/K$ be a homogeneous space. It is easy to show, that the left action of $G$ on itself by multiplication is a free and proper action.

My question is, if the induced action 
$$G  \times G/K \to G/K, \ (g, h.K) \mapsto (gh).K$$

of $G$ on $G/K$ is also proper? I already showed, that if the action is proper, we necessarily have, that $K$ is compact. But is this condition sufficient, too?

Edit:
An action $\phi \colon G \times M \to M$ is called proper, if the map 
$$G \times M \to M \times M, \quad (g,x) \mapsto (x, \phi(g,x))$$ is a proper map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "unbounded sequence" I mean one eventually escaping from any compact set. By bounded I mean contained in a compact set.

If it were not proper there would exist an unbounded sequence $g_n\in G$ and a bounded sequence $x_n$ such that $g_nx_n$ is bounded.  Choose representatives $\gamma_n\in G$ for each $x_n$.  Then since $G\rightarrow G/K$ is proper, $\gamma_n$ and $g_n\gamma_n$ are bounded sequences.  This contradicts the fact you already proved about the action of $G$ on itself.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what fact you mean? If the action is proper, then the map $$\Phi \colon G \times G/K \to G/K \times G/K$$ has to be proper. So taking now $[K] \times [K] \in G/K \times G/K$, which is compact since $[K] \in G/K$ is only a point, then $\Phi^{-1}([K],[K]) = (K,[K])$. Since this is compact, $K$ has to be compact.

Comment: I meant the fact that the left action of G on itself is proper.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I don't quite understand what you are trying to say. Could you make it a bit clearer? So are you making a contradiction, assuming the action is not proper? Or assuming it is proper? because first it seems that you are assuming it isn't proper and then you are using, that $G \to G/K$ is proper. I'm really confused about that.

Comment: okay I see, you are assuming that the action isn't proper, but since $K$ is compact, you say, that $G \to G/K$ is proper as map, not as action. Sorry.

Comment: No worries!  Is it okay now?